# Get key/value pair from Firebase response nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am getting the following response from a GET API call to Firebase database. It is a nested JSON objects.

I want to get all the values for key `name` from each nested object into an array using JavaScript

**GET REST API Response:**

```
{
  "barID1": {
    "address": "4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    "description": “description text”,
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1”,  "https:url2”, "https:url3” ],
    "lat": -34.810585,
    "lon": 138.616739,
    "name": "Africola",
    "phone": "(08) 8223 3885",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url”
  },
  "barID2": {
    "address": "138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
     "description": “description text”,
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1”,  "https:url2”, "https:url3” ],
    "lat": -34.848082,
    "lon": 138.599813,
    "name": "Disco Mexico Taqueria",
    "phone": "0416 855 108",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url”
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done using:

1. Using **[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** to accumulate the `name` values into a single array.
2. Using **[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and **[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to iterate through the keys and map it to the `name` array.
3. Using **[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)** and **[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**
4. Using **[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** and utilizing the second mapping function parameter to map individual objects to an array of `names`.

```js
const obj = {"barID1":{"address":"4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000","appStoreURL":"http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX","description":"description text","imgURLs":["Https:url1","https:url2","https:url3"],"lat":-34.810585,"lon":138.616739,"name":"Africola","phone":"(08) 8223 3885","status":"active","venueImgURL":"https:url"},"barID2":{"address":"138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000","appStoreURL":"http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX","description":"description text","imgURLs":["Https:url1","https:url2","https:url3"],"lat":-34.848082,"lon":138.599813,"name":"Disco Mexico Taqueria","phone":"0416 855 108","status":"active","venueImgURL":"https:url"}};

//using Object.values & reduce
let name = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, ele) =>{
 return acc.concat(ele.name)
}, []);
console.log(name);

//using Object.keys & map 
name = Object.keys(obj).map((ele) => obj[ele]['name']);
console.log(name);

//using Object.values & map
name = Object.values(obj).map((ele) => ele.name);
console.log(name);

//using Array.from
name = Array.from(Object.values(obj), ele => ele.name);
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Please not that solutions 3 and 4 are ECMA 2015/2017. This may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the values of the input object via `Object.values()` and then `map()` the `name` from each `object` value as shown below to achieve this:

```js
const data = {
    barID1: {
    address: "4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000",
    appStoreURL: "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    description: "description text",
    imgURLs: [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    lat: -34.810585,
    lon: 138.616739,
    name: "Africola",
    phone: "(08) 8223 3885",
    status: "active",
    venueImgURL: "https:url"
  },
    barID2: {
    address: "138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000",
    appStoreURL: "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    description: "description text",
    imgURLs: [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    lat: -34.848082,
    lon: 138.599813,
    name: "Disco Mexico Taqueria",
    phone: "0416 855 108",
    status: "active",
    venueImgURL: "https:url"
  }
}

console.log( Object.values(data).map(object => object.name) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I use `for in` to loop each object in your JSON then push the name into the result array.

```js
const data = {
  "barID1": {
    "address": "4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": ["Https:url1", "https: url2", "https:url3"],
    "lat": -34.810585,
    "lon": 138.616739,
    "name": "Africola",
    "phone": "(08) 8223 3885",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  },
  "barID2": {
    "address": "138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": ["Https:url1", "https: url2", "https:url3"],
    "lat": -34.848082,
    "lon": 138.599813,
    "name": "Disco Mexico Taqueria",
    "phone": "0416 855 108",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  }
}

let result = []
for (let i in data) {
  result.push(data[i].name)
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of the json structure.

```js
const json = {
  "barID1": {
    "address": "4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.810585,
    "lon": 138.616739,
    "name": "Africola",
    "phone": "(08) 8223 3885",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  },
  "barID2": {
    "address": "138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
     "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.848082,
    "lon": 138.599813,
    "name": "Disco Mexico Taqueria",
    "phone": "0416 855 108",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  }
};

let res = Object.values(json).map(({name}) => name);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is `Object.values`:

```js
const data = {"barID1":{"address":"4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000","appStoreURL":"http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX","description":"description text","imgURLs":["Https:url1","https:url2","https:url3"],"lat":-34.810585,"lon":138.616739,"name":"Africola","phone":"(08) 8223 3885","status":"active","venueImgURL":"https:url"},"barID2":{"address":"138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000","appStoreURL":"http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX","description":"description text","imgURLs":["Https:url1","https:url2","https:url3"],"lat":-34.848082,"lon":138.599813,"name":"Disco Mexico Taqueria","phone":"0416 855 108","status":"active","venueImgURL":"https:url"}};
const namesArr = Object.values(data).map(({ name }) => name);
console.log(namesArr);
```